# Change x and y labels on a gbm partial plot

Tags: r, plot, gbm

I am having trouble changing the x and y labels on a partial plot for a gbm model. I need to rename them for the journal article.

I read this in and create the plot as follows:

```
library(gbm)
final<- readRDS(final_gbm_model)
summary(final, n.trees=final$n.trees)
```

Here is the summary output:

```
                                                        var   rel.inf
ProbMn50ppb                                       ProbMn50ppb 11.042750
ProbDOpt5ppm                                     ProbDOpt5ppm  7.585275
Ngw_1975                                             Ngw_1975  6.314080
PrecipMinusETin_1971_2000_GWRP PrecipMinusETin_1971_2000_GWRP  4.988598
N_total                                               N_total  4.776950
DTW60YrJurgens                                 DTW60YrJurgens  4.415016
CVHM_TextZone                                   CVHM_TextZone  4.225048
RiverDist_NEAR                                 RiverDist_NEAR  4.165035
LateralPosition                               LateralPosition  4.036406
CAML1990_natural_water                 CAML1990_natural_water  3.720303
PctCoarseMFUpActLayer                   PctCoarseMFUpActLayer  3.668184
BioClim_BIO12                                   BioClim_BIO12  3.561071
MFDTWSpr2000Faunt                           MFDTWSpr2000Faunt  3.383900
PBot_krig                                           PBot_krig  3.362289
WaterUse2                                           WaterUse2  3.291040
AVG_CLAY                                             AVG_CLAY  3.280454
Age_yrs                                               Age_yrs  3.144734
MFVelSept2000                                   MFVelSept2000  3.064030
AVG_SILT                                             AVG_SILT  2.882709
ScreenLength                                     ScreenLength  2.683542
HydGrp_C                                             HydGrp_C  2.666106
AVG_POR                                               AVG_POR  2.563147
MFVelFeb2000                                     MFVelFeb2000  2.505106
HiWatTabDepMin                                 HiWatTabDepMin  2.421521
RechargeAnnualmmWolock                 RechargeAnnualmmWolock  2.252706
```

I can create a partial dependence plot as follows:

```
plot(final,"ProbMn50ppb",n.trees=final$n.trees)
```

[image]
But if I try to set the label arguments I get the following error:

```
 plot(final,"ProbMn50ppb",n.trees=final$n.trees,ylab="LNNO3")

Error in plot.default(X$X1, X$y, type = "l", xlab = x$var.names[i.var],  : 
  formal argument "ylab" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

How can I change the y and x axis labels?

Comment: Thank you for trying to provide your data but we don't allow personal cloud links because of malware and because they break over time. Also as a best practice and to avoid file corruption I'd recommend that you give your RDS files the extension of ".RDS".

Comment: Okay, thank you! Is there a better way to provide data like this?

Comment: Usually it's best to recreate what you can within your code and to `dput()` anything else. That way it's easily reproducible and contains all class/meta data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `plot.gbm` function passes its own name to the generic plot function so the two are colliding. So you will not be able to customize the plot the way you want in that mode. But the authors did provide an alternative when you set `return.grid=TRUE`. Instead of building a plot, it will output the data itself. You can then use that for any plot including ggplot2.

```
plotdata <- plot(gbm1, return.grid=TRUE)
plot(plotdata, type="l", ylab="ylab", xlab="xlab")
```

[image]

*Example data from help(gbm)*

Comment: This is much better than the solution I was thinking of, which would be to modify the source code (because `plot.gbm` includes both default labs and `...`, which is where the trouble comes from).

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the gbm object itself before plotting (or in a function):

```
your_gbm_obj$var.names[index] = "axis label"
```